# Checking if float3 passed boundary

Tags: shader, hlsl, cg

I have the following code:

```
(voxelCoord.x < 0 ||  
voxelCoord.y < 0 || voxelCoord.z < 0 || voxelCoord.x > 1 
|| voxelCoord.y > 1 || voxelCoord.z > 1)
```

However, I think it should be possible to optimize this. I think using min and max will set me back, is there a solution like clamp which will let me check if the boundaries are passed?

For instance; would

> clamp(voxelCoord, float3(0), float3(1)) != voxelCoord

work?

Comment: You could do frac(voxelCoord) != voxelCoord but it won't account properly for exactly 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any(voxelCoord < 0 || voxelCoord > 1)

Is more concise and compiles down to 2 less D3D-IL instructions than what you've written. Whether it is any more optimal after the driver's compiler has had a go at optimising them  will depend on other factors (whether the hardware is vector-based or scalar-based for one).

Comment: I tried the GLSL equivalent of that; PVRShaderEditor tells me it equates to more instructions than the clamp and != combo.

Comment: Yeah, I think you might be right. If < 0 and > 1 are what you're interested in, give the compiler the best possible chance by using saturate rather than clamp too, as saturate is often a modifier the hardware can do for free on certain instructions. It may well spot the clamp is between 0 and 1 and use saturate anyway, but it can't hurt to put it in anyway.